# For any von Neumann algebra $A$, is there a commutative von Neumann algebra $C$ and a normal completely positive map $\alpha$ such that $\alpha C=A$

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

For any von Neumann algebra $A$, is there a commutative von Neumann algebra $C$ and a normal completely positive map $\alpha$ such that $\alpha C=A$ (or $\alpha C$ is dense w.r.t ultraweak topology)?